# Error: Cannot read property 'close' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

hello dear community im wondering myself why i get this error when i try to use mongodb and nodejs.

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/TodoApp', (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to MongoDB server.')
    }else{
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB server.')
    }
    db.close();
});
```

Output in the **console**:

> Unable to connect to MongoDB server.
>   C:\Users\eljubec\Desktop\node-todo-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
>             throw err
>             ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of null
>       at MongoClient.connect (C:\Users\eljubec\Desktop\node-todo-api\playground\mongodb-connect.js:9:8)
>       at connectCallback (C:\Users\eljubec\Desktop\node-todo-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:527:5)
>       at C:\Users\eljubec\Desktop\node-todo-api\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:418:11
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:150:11)

Comment: If the connection fails, `db` is going to be `null`. Move the close command inside your `else` block.

Comment: Obviously there is a problem connecting to MongoDB. Why don't you log `err` to see what it is?

Comment: try to add "console.log(err)"  in your first if statment and show us the result

Comment: As the other comments said: Your output is showing an err connecting to the database. When the database doesn't connect, your db object is going to be null, and therefore not have a close method.

Comment: { MongoError: connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connection 0 to localhost:27017 timed out' }

Comment: im getting this back

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check if your MongoDB service is up and running on the given port. Open a Command Prompt (`WindowsKey+R->cmd->OK`) and run the following command:

```
netstat -a | find "27017"
```

This should give you some output like this:

```
TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        <MACHINE_NAME>:0         LISTENING
```

If you don't see this line you need to start MongoDB or make sure it runs on the default port.

The second error `"Cannot read property 'close' of null"` is simply because the connection fails so your `db` variable will hold a `null` value according to the [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#connect) which obviously you cannot run a `close()` on. You might want to move that `close()` statement inside the `else` statement.